# Estimating instrument uncertainty from the errors in the measurement of different objects

Tags: error-analysis

I want to know the measurement uncertainty of an analytic balance. From 4 repeated measurements of a single 50 cents coin, I got a standard deviation of 0.4 mg. From 4 repeated measurements of 1 euro coin, I got a standard deviation of 1.0 mg.  Am I correct in assuming that I can obtain an estimate of the error in the balance as

$\sqrt{0.4^2+1.0^2}$   ?

Comment: What were your measured masses of the coins?

Comment: the 50 cent coin is 7.8658 g and the 1 euro is 7.5086 g. A larger, 2 euro coin, is 8.4748 +/-0.0004 g, and a smaller 20 cent coin is 4.1074 +/- 0.0005 g so the absolute error is not significantly correlated with coin size.